# What is the source of the "Versatile Channeler" feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I'm building my first pathfinder game and am a Cleric under a neutral diety. I was looking at feats and found the "Versatile Channeller" feat but I can't find it anywhere in the player's guide. Is it an unofficial feat?

Answer (score 6):

The feat [Versatile Channeler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/versatile-channeler) is from Paizo's [*Ultimate Magic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601252994) (2011), which is about as official as sources get, really. The *d20 Pathfinder SRD* often lists the textual locations of material it presents at the bottom of its pages.

Comment: Thanks so much, I just visited  the page again and the source was clearly there, I have no idea how i missed it.